# Addressing a WPS using Geotools' ExecuteProcessRequest

Tags: geotools, wps, wsdl

I am trying to address a WPS that is running on a known machine to retrieve some isochrones. Below are excerpts from the relevant parts of the WSDL of said server:

```
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0">
        <element name="ExecuteProcess_xxx_isochrones">
            <complexType>
                <sequence>
                    <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="network_id" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="y_coord" type="xsd:float"/>
                    <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="x_coord" type="xsd:float"/>
                </sequence>
            </complexType>
        </element>
    </schema>
    <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0">
        <element name="ExecuteProcess_xxx_isochronesResponse">
            <complexType>
                <sequence>
                    <element name="isochrones_pngResult" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                    <element name="isochrones_gmlResult" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                </sequence>
            </complexType>
        </element>
    </schema>
    <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0">
        <element name="ExecuteProcessAsync_xxx_isochrones">
            <complexType>
                <sequence>
                    <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="network_id" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="y_coord" type="xsd:float"/>
                    <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="x_coord" type="xsd:float"/>
                </sequence>
            </complexType>
        </element>
    </schema>
    <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0">
        <element name="ExecuteProcessAsync_xxx_isochronesResponse">
            <complexType>
                <sequence>
                    <element name="statusURLResult" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                </sequence>
            </complexType>
        </element>
    </schema>
```

Here are the capabilities as retrieved from the server:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wps:ExecuteResponse xmlns:wps="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0/wpsExecute_response.xsd" service="WPS" version="1.0.0" xml:lang="en-CA" serviceInstance="ourServerUrl?service=WPS&amp;request=GetCapabilities&amp;version=1.0.0">
<wps:Process wps:processVersion="0.1">
    <ows:Identifier>xxx_isochrones</ows:Identifier>
    <ows:Title>XXX Isochrones</ows:Title>
    <ows:Abstract>This process calculates isochrones.</ows:Abstract>
</wps:Process>
<wps:Status creationTime="2015-08-31T11:55:20Z">
    <wps:ProcessSucceeded>Process xxx_isochrones successfully calculated</wps:ProcessSucceeded>
</wps:Status>
<wps:ProcessOutputs>
    <wps:Output>
        <ows:Identifier>isochrones_png</ows:Identifier>
        <ows:Title>Isochrones PNG</ows:Title>
        <ows:Abstract>PNG showing segments of isochrones
                        for 5, 10 and 20 minutes of traveltime
                        for the chosen means of transport.
                        It reassembles the given bounding box</ows:Abstract>
        <wps:Reference href="ourServerUrl/wpsoutputs/isochrones_png-6027d3d4-4fc6-11e5-9303-005056a52e0d.png" mimeType="image/png" />
    </wps:Output>
    <wps:Output>
        <ows:Identifier>isochrones_gml</ows:Identifier>
        <ows:Title>Isochrones GML</ows:Title>
        <ows:Abstract>GML vector data consisting of segments of isochrones
                        for 5, 10 and 20 minutes of traveltime
                        for the chosen means of transport.</ows:Abstract>
        <wps:Reference href="ourServerUrl/wpsoutputs/isochrones_gml-6027d3d4-4fc6-11e5-9303-005056a52e0d.gml" mimeType="text/xml" />
    </wps:Output>
</wps:ProcessOutputs>
```

To address the service I am doing the following (error and exception handling removed to increase readability):

```
// The WeProcessingServiceManager manages a map of already instantiated services, nothing fancy.
WebProcessingService wps = WebProcessingServiceManager.getServiceFor(new URL("ourServerURL"));

ExecuteProcessRequest request = wps.createExecuteProcessRequest();
request.setIdentifier("xxx_isochrones");
request.addInput("network_id", Arrays.asList(wps.createLiteralInputValue("bicycles")));
request.addInput("x_coord", Arrays.asList(wps.createLiteralInputValue("1234567")));
request.addInput("y_coord", Arrays.asList(wps.createLiteralInputValue("1234567")));

ResponseDocumentType doc = wps.createResponseDocumentType(false, true, true, "isochrones_pngResult");
DocumentOutputDefinitionType odt = (DocumentOutputDefinitionType) doc.getOutput().get(0);
odt.setMimeType("image/png");
odt.setAsReference(true);
ResponseFormType responseForm = wps.createResponseForm(doc, null);
request.setResponseForm(responseForm);

ExecuteProcessResponse response = wps.issueRequest(request);
```

Unfortunately it seems that I cannot extract the desired result. I am not sure why it isn't working. I followed a very basic tutorial who doesn't explain much. I also find the documentation lacking.

Would anyone have an idea how to extract the desired result, that is, the PNG or at least the URL of the png?

To verify the service I invoke the following URL:

```
http://[our server URL]?
REQUEST=Execute&
IDENTIFIER=gtui_isochrones&
SERVICE=WPS&
VERSION=1.0.0&
DATAINPUTS=
network_id=pedestrian;
x_coord=682884;
y_coord=6371184
```

This is the response I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wps:ExecuteResponse [namespaces and stuff] service="WPS" version="1.0.0" xml:lang="en-CA" serviceInstance="http:[our server URL]?service=WPS&amp;request=GetCapabilities&amp;version=1.0.0">
<wps:Process wps:processVersion="0.1">
    <ows:Identifier>xxx_isochrones</ows:Identifier>
    <ows:Title>XXX Isochrones</ows:Title>
    <ows:Abstract>This process calculates isochrones.</ows:Abstract>
</wps:Process>
<wps:Status creationTime="2015-09-02T12:46:28Z">
    <wps:ProcessSucceeded>Process xxx_isochrones successfully calculated</wps:ProcessSucceeded>
</wps:Status>
<wps:ProcessOutputs>
    <wps:Output>
        <ows:Identifier>isochrones_png</ows:Identifier>
        <ows:Title>Isochrones PNG</ows:Title>
        <ows:Abstract>PNG showing segments of isochrones
                        for 5, 10 and 20 minutes of traveltime
                        for the chosen means of transport.
                        It reassembles the given bounding box</ows:Abstract>
        <wps:Reference href="http:[our server URL]/wpsoutputs/isochrones_png-d716304a-515f-11e5-b2d0-005056a52e0d.png" mimeType="image/png" />
    </wps:Output>
    <wps:Output>
        <ows:Identifier>isochrones_gml</ows:Identifier>
        <ows:Title>Isochrones GML</ows:Title>
        <ows:Abstract>GML vector data consisting of segments of isochrones
                        for 5, 10 and 20 minutes of traveltime
                        for the chosen means of transport.</ows:Abstract>
        <wps:Reference href="http:[our server URL]/wpsoutputs/isochrones_gml-d716304a-515f-11e5-b2d0-005056a52e0d.gml" mimeType="text/xml" />
    </wps:Output>
</wps:ProcessOutputs>
```

Comment: do you get any response? Did you try with another client to rule out issues with the service (http://docs.geoserver.org/2.7.1/user/extensions/wps/requestbuilder.html)? What is the link to the tutorial? For an unsupported module the docs seem really good - http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/unsupported/wps.html

Comment: Is that all the code? Where are you exactly extracting the outputs? And are you sure that request is requiring outputs embodied in the response?

Comment: I used the tutorial you linked as well: http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/unsupported/wps.html Furthermore I can verify that a result is generated when the input parameters are added. A query build by hand worked just fine in the browser.

Comment: Eric, please add to your question the query you used to verify the service is functional and the answer you received back. Also, please clarify if you are invoking the service in synchronous or asynchronous mode.

Comment: I added the information to the question. I use an asynchronous mode I believe. While I wait for a response, that is, maintain the connection, my application does not block and simply retrieves the result when it is available.